# nfs-kernel-server starts too early

Tags: systemd, nfs, startup, raspbian

I have an RPI-based NFS server with an external USB hard disk. After a recent upgrade to Raspbian 8.0 and systemd I noticed that now nfs-kernel-server seems to be starting before all file systems on the external disk are mounted:

> `Jun 29 12:01:33 nas nfs-kernel-server[369]: Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...exportfs: Failed to stat ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒(redacted): No such file or directory`

The nfs-kernel-server has a sysV startup script in `/etc/init.d`. I tried adding `$local_fs` to the list of its requirements, but it did not help. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

(I also see smartd starting before the udev tree is fully populated, but I'll save that for another question.)

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/fstab` you can try to add `x-systemd.before=nfs-kernel-server.service` as option to the mount maybe?

Comment: Thanks! It really helped.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to add a `sleep` to the `nfs-kernel-server` script.

Open up the script with:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server
```

Scroll down and find the `start()` section (it's usally under the first `case`) and add a sleep for 30 seconds under `start`:

```
sleep 30
```

Save and exit.

Comment: Thanks. That's will be the hack of the last resort. I did not loose hope yet to find a solution...